# How to view 3d html5/css3/native javascript page stereoscopically on mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, virtual-reality

Short version:  Kieth Clark has a 3D html fps shooter demo.  It uses 3d tansforms on html5 elements to produce a 3D world experience.  It is not VR.  Is there an API to view it stereoscopically?

I have a similar engine.  I came up with a way to view it stereoscopically using Cardboard-style viewer, 3D TV/Monitor, or red/cyan anaglyph glasses.  I had to use a pair of iframes, however, and load a copy of the "world" document into each frame, however.

This doubles the load on the gpu, however, requires duplicates of all changes to "the world" for both iframes, and workarounds for focusable items such as textareas.  This all works great, but diminishes the capacity for detail without RAF noticably slowing down and getting jumpy.  Especially true in Firefox on mobile, and of course there is also the added problem of security limitations on iframes.

If theres an API to just view and control a 3D html5 page in stereo without explicitly duplicating everything that would make things a lot simpler and more efficient.

I'm using a Google Chrome on Galaxy Note 3 as my standard-level target-device, if anyone needs to know.

Long version (old):

I have a 3d game I'm writing with native html5/css3/javascript.  It is primarily for mobile and already contains a fully-functional camera system with the ability to zoom in or out of first-person, second-person, overhead etc, rotate the yaw and pitch of the view, as well as location on the map around the avatar, etc.  Is there an easy way to view it stereoscopically?  It will be embedded in an Android app, or at least accessed through one, or through Chrome as a web-app.  I thought Chrome Dev with VR Shell would be a possibility to try it out and hopefully integrate into an app eventually.  Not having luck with that yet.  Theoretically, I just need to be able to view an ordinary html5 page that has css3 3d transforms.  For example, if you had a 3d cube made of divs or whatever, to view it with two points of view, one for each eye, without changing anything in the page itself.  Basically, if you could view anything 3d in the page stereoscopically, much like the VR Shell sounds like, it should work.  All I seem to come up with is how to turn on the flag in Chrome Dev, but I'm not seeing anything to actually activate it.  It's been fully restarted etc.  The page is already 3d and fully-functional with orientation control in first-person or otherwise.  All I seem to find are how to turn it on or about 3d videos.  Can this be done in Googles VR libs for Studio without using all the other stuff?  I just need the second eyeball.  [image][image][image]

Comment: Please edit your wall of text into readable paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Was hoping an api existed for this, but my solution was to make a parent document with two iFrames and load the doc with the 3d tranforms into both iframes.  Then offset the perspective-origin in each about 1% (i.e. 49% in one and 51% in the other).  Worked great without added mods using device orientation, but obvi not for mouse control.  Ideally, both iframed documents should be controlled from js in the parent doc.  Downside is you have to control two objects for every change, and complications arise if you have inputs or textareas that take exclusive focus.  Fixed all that, but this is the down-low version of the solution.